# Microsoft WF .NET ExpressionText causes validation errors

Tags: c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

This is related to the Workflow Foundation .NET 4.0.  We have found that when setting the ExpressionText to a reserved keyword such as "interface" or "class", the underlying Validation Service in the foundation throws a validation message stating "one or more children have validation errors or warnings".

We are setting the ExpressionText of an argument like this:

```
        Argument inArg = Argument.Create(typeof(T), ArgumentDirection.In);

        inArg.Expression = new VisualBasicValue<T>
        {
            ExpressionText = selectedItem,
        };

        mp.SetValue(inArg);
```

Any idea if this is a known issue, and how we can handle it?

Comment: check this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2010/02/22/navigating-the-workflow-tree-wf-4-0-workflow-designer.aspx

Comment: not sure I follow how this helps this particular scenario?

Comment: What are the validation errors or warnings?  They tell you exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Its a known issue with the .net framework. Try and create a class with a property called class and attempt a compile. You cannot because they are reserved words.

Comment: so there is no way to handle this scenario then - unless we check for specific types in string format (hard coded) which is a bit ugly.